# Having question about publishing service in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

My cluster has one master and two slaves(not on any cloud platform), and I create a deployment with 2 replicas so each slave has one pod, the image I’m running is tensorflow-jupyter. Then I create a NodePort type service for this deployment and I thought I can separately run these two pods at the same time, but I was wrong.

Tensorflow-jupyter have to use token it gives to login, everything is fine if there has only 1 pod, but if the replicas is 2 or more, it will have server error after login and logout by itself after I press F5, then I can’t use the token to login anymore. Similar situation happens to Wordpress, too.

I think I shouldn’t use NodePort type to doing this, but I don’t know if other service type can solve this problem. I don’t have load balancer to try and I don’t know how to use ExternalName.

Is there has any way to expose a service for a deployment with 2 or more replicas(one pod per slave)? Or I only can create a lot of deployments all with 1 pod and then expose same amount of services for each deployment?

Answer (score 1):

It seems the application you're trying to deploy requires sticky session support: this is not supported out-of-the-box with the `NodePort` Service, you have to go for exposing your application using an Ingress resource controlled by an Ingress Controller in order to take advantage of the reverse-proxy capabilities (in this case, the sticky-session).

> I'm not suggesting you use the `sessionAffinity=ClientIP` Service option since it's allowed only for `ClusterIP` Service resources and according to your question it seems the application has to be accessed outside of the cluster.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I have another question is: should I find another node to be the ingress controller or I can just use master node?

Comment: Since the Control Plane is mission-critical for the whole Kubernetes cluster, I'd suggest you allocating the Ingress Controller to a specific node pool.